# Negation with quantors

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Negate the following:
$\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers.

**1) $ \forall a \in \mathbb{P} : \exists b \in \mathbb{P}: a|b$**

Neg:
$ \exists a \in \mathbb{P}: \forall b \in \mathbb{P}: a \not| b$

(I am having problems with the first sentence because both the sentence and the negation would be true?)

**2) $ \forall a \in \mathbb{P} : \forall b \in \mathbb{P}: (a|b \rightarrow a=b)$**

Neg: $\exists a \in \mathbb{P}: \exists b \in \mathbb{P}: (a|b \land a \neq b)$

**3) $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}: (a \neq 0 \land b \neq 0 \land a \cdot b =0)$**

Neg: $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}: (a = 0 \lor b=0 \lor a \cdot b \neq 0)$

I have tried to come up with the solutions myself, it would be great if some could check whether those are fine.

Comment: 1) is true: $n|n$ also for n prime. Thus, 2) is false.

Comment: Having said that all three are correct.